# How to pivot temp table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

```
      Date             Time        Mode ID
    2017-01-01  13:00:00.0000000    3   10
    2017-01-01  14:00:00.0000000    1   10
    2017-01-01  15:00:00.0000000    3   10
    2017-01-01  15:30:00.0000000    1   10
```

This is a temp table.I just want to display time column as 2 columns,1 column with mode =3  and other with mode=1.

This is a temp table.I just want the below output:

```
          Date         InTime(Mode-3)    OutTime(Mode-1)     ID

         2017-01-01   13:00:00.0000000  14:00:00.0000000    10

         2017-01-01   15:00:00.0000000  15:30:00.0000000    10
```

Comment: You should provide the results you are looking for and any attempts you have tried.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, depending on the data and datatypes/schema (and if the name of the table is ***timeTable***):

```
    SELECT DATE, time AS 'InTime(Mode-3)',
      (SELECT TOP 1 time FROM timeTable
          WHERE mode = 1 
            AND id = outerTable.id 
            AND date = outerTable.date 
            AND time > outerTable.time 
          ORDER BY date, time) AS 'OutTime(Mode-1)',
      ID
    FROM timeTable AS outerTable 
    WHERE mode = 3
```

> - the outerQuery only selects the in-times **mode = 3**
> - in innerQuery selects the next out-time, that correspondes to the selected in-time, and only returns the first one. since ordered by date and time, it should be the next one. *Only tested with your given data*

**Output:**

```
    Date       |  InTime(Mode-3)     |   OutTime(Mode-1)   |  ID
---------------|---------------------|---------------------|------
   2017-01-01  |  13:00:00.0000000   |  14:00:00.0000000   |  10
   2017-01-01  |  15:00:00.0000000   |  15:30:00.0000000   |  10
```

***Just for reference:***
I used this table schema

```
 CREATE TABLE timeTable(
     date DATE,
     time TIME,
     mode INTEGER,
     id INTEGER
 );
```

**Update:**
With time - difference:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,INTIME,OUTTIME) AS [DIFFERENCE] FROM (
    SELECT [DATE], [time] AS INTIME,
      (SELECT TOP 1 [time] FROM timeTable
          WHERE [mode] = 1 
            AND [id] = outerTable.id 
            AND [date] = outerTable.date 
            AND [time] > outerTable.time 
          ORDER BY [date], [time]) AS OUTTIME,
      [ID]
    FROM [timeTable] AS outerTable 
    WHERE [mode] = 3
) WholeData
```

Comment: also need to get the time difference in another column -winner_joiner

Comment: @michael `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, column1, column2)` this works

Comment: I tried it,But I actually insert it into a #temp table

SELECT DATE, time AS 'InTime(Mode-3)',
      (SELECT TOP 1 time FROM #timeTable
          WHERE mode = 1 
            AND id = outerTable.id 
            AND date = outerTable.date 
            AND time > outerTable.time 
          ORDER BY date, time) AS 'OutTime(Mode-1)',
      ID,DATEDIFF(mi,MIN(Time),MAX(Time) as BreakHours
  into #temp
    FROM #timeTable AS outerTable
    WHERE mode = 3
@winner_joiner

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you want a method to create alternating rows with fixed values (1 and 3).
you can use

**case when ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [Date])%2 = 0 then 1 else 3**

as the logic for your mode column

Comment: This is a temp table.I just want to display time column as 2 columns,1 column with mode =3 and other with mode=1

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @TB TABLE (DATETIME VARCHAR(30),ID INT)
INSERT INTO @TB VALUES
('2017-01-01 13:00:00.0000000',10),
('2017-01-01 14:00:00.0000000',10),
('2017-01-01 15:00:00.0000000',10),
('2017-01-01 15:30:00.0000000',10 )

SELECT  SUBSTRING(DATETIME,0,11) DATE
        ,SUBSTRING(DATETIME,12,LEN(DATETIME)) TIME
        ,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATETIME)%2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 3 END MODE
        ,ID
FROM    @TB
```